# after_sign_in_url_for(resource) from Scoped controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I'm inside of `Users::OmniauthCallbacksController` and trying to call `redirect_to after_sign_in_url_for(@user)` but `users/` is getting appended to my controller. How do I stop this from happening?

Some debugging:

```
>> after_sign_in_path_for(@user)
=> {:controller=>"expert_questions", :action=>"index"}
>> url_for(after_sign_in_path_for(@user))
!! #<ActionController::UrlGenerationError: No route matches {:action=>"index", :controller=>"users/expert_questions"}>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
  def after_sign_in_path_for(user)
    if user.admin
      '/admin'
    else
      '/'
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use url helper to redirect to `{:controller=>"expert_questions", :action=>"index"}`

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(@user)
  expert_questions_index_path
end
```